# ¿Cómo puedo obtener un arreglo en rails 5?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Solo quiero obtener un arreglo a partir de un ciclo, el cual se repite mientras tenga actividades registradas... Me explico mejor:
Un administrador crea un grupo, y asigna permisos para un crud, por cada actividad, para ello necesito un ciclo que recorra cada actividad y genere los campos de selección, por cada actividad

```
<% Activity.all.order(:id).each do |a| %>
    <br>
    <%= a.name %>
    <div class="input-field">
        <%= form.select "c[]", options_for_select([['No', false], ['Sí', true]], 1) %>
        <%= form.label "c[]", "¿Puede crear #{a.name}?"%>
    </div>
    <div class="input-field">
        <%= form.select "r[]", options_for_select([['No', false], ['Sí', true]], 1) %>
        <%= form.label "r[]", "¿Puede ver #{a.name}?"%>
    </div>
    <div class="input-field">
        <%= form.select "u[]", options_for_select([['No', false], ['Sí', true]], 1) %>
        <%= form.label "u[]", "¿Puede actualizar #{a.name}?"%>
    </div>
    <div class="input-field">
        <%= form.select "d[]", options_for_select([['No', false], ['Sí', true]], 1) %>
        <%= form.label "d[]", "¿Puede borrar #{a.name}?"%>
    </div>
    <div class="input-field">
        <%= form.select "p[]", options_for_select([['No', false], ['Sí', true]], 2) %>
        <%= form.label "p[]", "¿Solo administra sus propi@s #{a.name}?"%>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

Controller:

```
def user_params
    params.permit(:user_id)
end

def permission_params
    params.permit(:c, :r, :u, :d, :p)
end

def group_params
    params.require(:group).permit(:name, :description)
end
```

Y aunque le pase valores, no los recibe:
raise params[:group].to_yaml

```
":c"=>[],
":r"=>[],
":u"=>[],
":d"=>[],
":p"=>[],
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo creo tu problema va en que estás usando [`select`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/select) en vez de [`select_tag`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/select_tag), que es lo que se usa cuando es un atributo virtual (asumo que tu modelo no tiene atributos :c, :r, :u, :d o :p).